# Send notification email to attendees when creating new event to o365 calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using MS Graph API to create events (meetings) into peoples calendars. 
We used to have on-premise Office and creating an event would automatically notify the persons about a new calendar event.

After migrating to o365 we started using Graph- Calendar API to create these events. Now the attendees get no email notification at all.

When you open the event from the outlook calendar, the To- field is empty. My guess is that this could be the cause, but I am not sure at all.

Here is an example json I am sending to the api:

```
{   Id:null,
Subject: Test,
Body:
    {ContentType:html,Content:Hey, <br/><br/>\\r\\nWhy you no send email!},
ShowAs:busy,
Attendees:[
{EmailAddress:{
    address:Matti.Lindroth@mycompany.fi,
    name:Lindroth Matti},
    Type:required}],
Start:
    {
    DateTime:2019-10-21T08:00:00,
    TimeZone:FLE Standard Time
    },
ResponseRequested:true,
IsOrganizer:true,
Organizer: 
    {EmailAddress:{
        address:Matti.Lindroth@mycompany.fi,
        name:Lindroth Matti}
    },
End:
    {
    DateTime:2019-10-21T08:30:00,
    TimeZone:FLE Standard Time
    },
    Sensitivity:null
```

}

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are both the organizer and the attendee in your example. In this case the server would not send you a meeting request, since you're the organizer! If you add someone else in your attendees collection they will receive a meeting request.

Comment: I tried changing the organizer to other user account but no luck. Thanks for the answer anyway. Gave me something to try out.

Comment: You can't set the organizer. It will always be "you" (the authenticated user). You need to send it to someone else to get the meeting requests to go out.

Comment: you are correct. I was sending the api call to url, which had my username in it and trying to make an appointment to myself. This is of course interpreted by the api as me making event to my own calendar.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out @Jason Johnston had it correct in the comments. I will post an answer here for better readability.

I was sending the HTTP post to url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/matti.lindroth@mycompany.fi/calendar/events

As you can see the url has my username in it, so the api assumes I was creating an event to my own calendar. I changed the url to use our technical user name instead and it started working.